# Наведение на два объекта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

```
            <div class="menuHref"><a href="#">Бизнес-планирование</a><img src="arrow.png"></div>
```

подскажите как сделать, чтобы при наведении на ссылку окрашивался текст ссылки а в img подгружалась другая картинка, и наоборот, при наведении на картинку - менялась картинка и цвет ссылки

Answer (score 1):

https://api.jquery.com/hover/

```js
$(".menuHref").hover(
  function() { //mousein
    var $target = $(this)
    $target.find("a").css("color", "red");//new color
    $target.find("img").attr("src", "new_image_link");//new image
  },
  function() { //mouseout
    var $target = $(this)
    $target.find("a").css("color", "");//restore color
    $target.find("img").attr("src", "old_image_link");//restore old image
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuHref"><a href="#">Бизнес-планирование</a><img src="arrow.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше это делать через CSS.
Будут следующие правила:

```
.menuHref a {
}
.menuHref img{
}
.menuHref:hover a {
}
.menuHref:hover img{
}
```

Тогда правила hover будут применяться при наведении на весь блок (на изображение и на ссылку).
И картинку лучше тоже в CSS указывать.

Для JS если что решение будет таким же — вешать событие на контейнер общий и уже изменять свойства "детей".

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".rightCenter").hover(
  function() { //mousein
    var $target = $(this)
    $target.find("a").css("color", "red");//new color
    $target.find("img").attr("src", "new_image_link");//new image
  },
  function() { //mouseout
    var $target = $(this)
    $target.find("a").css("color", "");//restore color
    $target.find("img").attr("src", "old_image_link");//restore old image
  }
)
```

```css
a{
 color:#fdfbfb;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: all 0.4s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #2987ac;
 transition: all 0.4s;
}

.active-link{

transition: all 0.4s;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rightCenter">
 <div id="bel" onClick="myFunction()" style="display:none">
 <a href="#" class="active-link" id="aclb">БЕЛАРУСЬ</a> 
  <div class="rightBottom"  id="b_phone">
     +3-211-111-111-11
  </div>
 </div>
     
 <img src="img/top.png" class="arrow_top" id="art" >
 <div id="russ" onClick="myFunction2()" style="display:none">
   <a href="#" class="active-link" id="aclr">РОССИЯ</a> 
 </div>
</div>
```

В чем проблема?